# How to print diferent pages with code in one pdf file?

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, pdf

I have this code, but when with the else conditions, he print a lot of pdf files, I want he print only one.
From page 1 to 4 it will always print, from 5 to 6 it will depend on the value of cell p205 and n272. Page 7 also always prints. The question is if you have for example 0 on p205, this code will create 3 PDFs, but I just want you to create a single PDF with page 1, 2, 3, 4, 6 and 7

```
Sub PrintToPageX()
Application.ActivePrinter = "Microsoft Print To PDF on Ne02:"
With Worksheets("Anexo Financeiro")
    If .Range("p205") = 1 And .Range("n272") = 1 Then
        .PrintOut From:=1, To:=7
    Else
        .PrintOut From:=1, To:=4
        If .Range("p205") = 1 Then .PrintOut From:=5, To:=5
        If .Range("n272") = 1 Then .PrintOut From:=6, To:=6
        .PrintOut From:=7, To:=7
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't understand what the issue is here. Change the `Else` code. If you are having problems doing that, we will gladly help you, but we would need to know what the desired result is.

Comment: From page 1 to 4 it will always print, from 5 to 6 it will depend on the value of cell p205 and n272. Page 7 also always prints.
The question is if you have for example 0 on p205, this code will create 3 PDFs, but I just want you to create a single PDF with page 1, 2, 3, 4, 6 and 7